# Can I use a parameter to specify from which of my subclasses I want to open an instance of my parent class?

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass

I have a parent class Bank.java which requires the name of the bank that I am trying to open and an int (account limit). I have two subclasses of Bank.java, one of which looks like this:

```
package uebungbank;
public class UniCredit extends Bank{
    public UniCredit(String name, int kreditlimit){
        super(name, kreditlimit);
    }
}
```

The openBankaccount method of Bank.java looks like this:

```
public void openBankaccount(String name, int kreditlimit){
        this.name = name;
        this.kreditlimit = kreditlimit;
    }
```

When trying to open a bank account, how can I make the **String name** be what specifies what type of Bank I open (aka which subclass I use)?

Comment: About your other question: "_EVERYBODY SHOULD LEARN TO PROGRAM A COMPUTER BECAUSE IT TEACHES YOU HOW TO THINK_" - https://trinket.io/python3/883c57bbf9

Comment: Nice solution! This is how I managed to solve it after sleeping on it - https://repl.it/@edrik16/6-Exercise-3#main.py

Comment: No need for  `rules = json.loads(rules_json)`  as you can use `rules_json`directly. You need way less code that you used, but if it works and you've learned in the process, that's the most important. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called the [Factory Pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm), which is a design pattern that described how to translate a set of parameters (in your case the String `name`) into an instance of the appropriate subclass.

Essentially, you want to create a method that contains the mappings from `name` to a subclass. A simple way of doing this would be just a set of if-else statements:

```java
// returns bank based on name
private Bank getBank(String name, int kreditlimit) {
    if (name.equals("UniCredit")) {
        return new UniCredit(name, kreditlimit);
    } else if (name.equals("SomeOtherBank")) {
        return new SomeOtherBank(name, kreditlimit);
    } else {
        throw new Exception("No bank found");
    }
}
```

However, this does not account for lower/uppercase in the name so you'll have to check that manually or convert everything to the same case. Also, each new bank will require an additional if-else. A more elegant way would be to replace strings with an Enum:

```java
enum BankType {
    UNICREDIT, SOMEOTHERBANK, ANOTHERBANK;
}

// returns bank based on name
private Bank getBank(BankType name, int kreditlimit) {
    select name {
        case UNICREDIT:
            return new UniCredit(name.toString(), kreditlimit);
        case SOMEOTHERBANK:
            return new SomeOtherBank(name.toString(), kreditlimit);
        case ANOTHERBANK:
            return new AnotherBank(name.toString(), kreditlimit);
        default:
            throw new Exception("No bank found");
    }
}
```

You could write this even more concisely by storing the class object for each subclass as a field in the enum itself, and then using `Class.newInstance` to create the appropriate subclass:

```java
enum BankType {
    UNICREDIT(UniCredit.class),
    SOMEOTHERBANK(SomeOtherBank.class),
    ANOTHERBANK(AnotherBank.class);

    private Class subclass;

    BankType(Class subclass) {
        this.subclass = subclass;
    }

    public Class getSubclass() { return this.subclass; }
}

// returns bank based on name
private Bank getBank(BankType name, int kreditlimit) {
    Bank bank = name.getSubclass();
    bank.setName(name.toString())
    bank.setLimit(kreditlimit);
    return bank;
}
```